# How to skip several rows in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm reading a csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv')
```

and get this error:

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 196, saw 4
```

So I put:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv',skiprows=196)
```

Now I ge:

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 203, saw 5
```

I try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv',skiprows=196,203)
```

and

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv',skiprows=[196,203])
```

Neither work

Edit.

when I try:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('items_sch_1.csv',skiprows=[196,203])
```

I got:

```
 Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 196, saw 4
```

Comment: What do you mean neither work... `skiprows=196` means skip the first 196 rows, `skiprows=[196,203]` means just skip the rows 196 and 203... You may need to look at pre-processing your data to get it to suitable quality.

Comment: when I try:  df = pd.read_csv('items_sch_1.csv',skiprows=[196,203])     I get: rror tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 196, saw 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to skip all bad lines, you can load your csv with

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

This will print out a warning for every row that is skipped, so you know how many errors there are.